# VSCode inverse of ctrl+L(line selection)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to reverse a line selection that is triggered when entering "ctrl+L" in VSCode. The default binding for "Expand Line Selection" is set to "Shrink Line Selection" in the case of skipping over the desired stopping point. Otherwise, it might have to be something done as a feature request to "Shrink Line Selection". Or maybe even just going back to Vim.

Comment: try `Shift+ArrowUp`

Comment: @rioV8 how about if we have 5 line then when to descending the line of code without plugin ? there is any shortcut tricky ?